# Do we need the axiom of choice when extracting a linearly independent spanning set from any spanning set of a separable Hilbert space?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, axiom-of-choice

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $\{v_n\}$ be some countable subset of $H$ such that its linear span is dense in $H$. $\{v_n\}$ need NOT be linearly independent.

(Here, linear independence of a countable set means that its any finite subset is linearly independent in the sense of linear algebra.)

Then, I guess I can extract a subset of $\{v_n\}$ that is linearly independent and span the same dense subspace of $H$. But, in this process, am I required to use the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: What argument do you have to extract such a subset, and why do you think it might need the axiom of choice?

Comment: I may proceed by choosing one element of $\{v_n\}$ at a step, just as in the finite dimensional case. However, then I guess Zorn's Lemma is unavoidable?

Comment: Why is it unavoidable? Is Zorn's lemma necessary to prove that an infinite subset of $\Bbb N$ is countable?

Comment: I have to "obtain" or "extract" a subset of $\{v_n\}$ that is linearly independent and still dense in $H$. Even a separable Hilbert space requires Zorn's lemma to show existence of an orthonormal basis..

Comment: Oh, I will correct myself. I meant to say "its linear span" is dense.

Comment: Then my initial comment, which I immediately deleted, was right: you do not need AC because your subsequence $(v_{n_k})_k$ is explicitely (inductively) defined: $n_{k+1}$ is the smallest $n$ s.t. $(v_{n_1},\dots,v_{n_k},v_n)$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Oh I see. That is something different from AC... Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with Hilbert spaces. It is just extracting a basis from a spanning sequence of a vector space (over any field).